# Ring below Dedekind domain is Dedekind domain.

Tags: commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

**Question**

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with quotient field $K$ and $L$ a subfield of $K$ such that $R$ is integral over $R\cap L$. Show that $R'=R\cap L$ is a Dedekind domain.

**Attempt**

I have shown that $R'$ is integrally closed domain whose every non-zero prime ideal is maximal. Can anyone assist me on showing $R'$ to be Noetherian.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to reason that if $R$ is Krull then $R'$ is Krull, even without the integrity assumption? I don't know how to argue for noetherianity directly, but that bypasses it, since then integrity gives you 1 dimensionality and 1-dim Krull domains are precisely the Dedekind. Subrings with reduced quotient fields, as such ring extensions are called in the literature, are a pretty standard topic in multiplicative ideal theory because their behavior is totally determined by divisorial ideals.

Comment: The textbook doesn't define Krull Rings. But I have read the definition of Krull Rings and I understand what you are trying to say. Still I don't know how $R'$ is Krull if $R$ is.

Comment: what textbook are you working from? If I know what you know I might be able to give you a more helpful answer (no promises)

Comment: Textbook : N.S Gopalakrishnan Commutative Algebra

Comment: The Section 5.3 of this book contains Dedekind domains proving basic results concerning them. Exercise is at the end of this section.

Comment: I see that you already got an answer you are satisfied with, but I wrote up an alternative answer anyway because I think (and hope) that it is instructive.  It offers another way to think about this problem in terms of descent of closure properties and ACC on divisorial ideals.  Basically, once you know that Krull = CIC + Mori, the solution to this exercise is just a couple lines long and not too remarkable!

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. I had never even heard of Mori domains. I will go through your answer definitely and learn new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an integral domain with quotient field $K$, let $L$ be a subfield of $K$, and set $B = A \cap L$.  This note is adapted from elements of S. Oda's exposition in the paper [On a Subring of an Integral Domain Obtained by Intersecting a Field](http://www.math.okayama-u.ac.jp/mjou/mjou1-46/mjou_pdf/mjou_37/mjou_37_037.pdf).  In that paper, $B = A \cap L$ is termed a *subring of $A$ with reduced quotient field*.

Observe that we can assume $L$ is the quotient field of $B$.  (Indeed, if the quotient field of $B$ were $L'$, then it is easily checked that $L' \subseteq L$ and hence $B = A \cap L'$.)

For any fractional ideal $I$ of a domain $A$ with quotient field $K$, let $I^{-1} = (A :_K I)$ and $I_v = (I^{-1})^{-1}$.  The *divisorial* fractional ideals are the ideals such that $I_v = I$.  Recall the following facts about the $v$-operation:
(i) $A_v = A$ and $(qI)_v = qI_v$ for any $q \in K$
(ii) $I \subseteq I_v$ and $I \subseteq J \implies I_v \subseteq J_v$, and
(iii) $(I_v)_v = I_v$.
More generally these are the defining properties of so-called $*$-operations.

It is an easy exercise to show that $I_v = \bigcap_{q \in K, I \subseteq qA}qA$, i.e. the divisorial closure of an ideal is the intersection of the principal fractional ideals containing it.

> **Lemma**: Let $B = A \cap L$, so that $L$ is the quotient field of $A \cap L$.  Let $v$ denote the $v$-operation in $A$.  For every divisorial ideal $I$ of $B$, it holds $I = (IA)_v \cap L$.

**Proof**: Let $q \in L$.  First it is trivial to argue that $qA \cap L = qB$.  Now suppose $I$ is divisorial, so that $I = \bigcap_{q \in L, I \subseteq qB} qB$.
Then by the characterization of divisorial ideals as intersections of principal fractional ideals containing them, we have $I \subseteq L \cap (IA)_v = L \cap \bigcap_{q \in K, IA \subseteq qA} qA \subseteq L \cap \bigcap_{q \in L, I \subseteq qB} qB = I$.  $\square$

A domain is called *Mori* if it satisfies the ascending chain condition on divisorial ideals.  This will be the lens through which we observe the descent of finiteness conditions from $A$ to $A \cap L$.

> ### **Examples of properties that always descend from $A$ to $A \cap L$**.
>
> - Mori
> - Ascending Chain condition on principal ideals
> - Valuation domain
> - Integrally closed
> - Completely integrally closed
> - Krull
> - DVR

**Proof**:
The descent of the chain conditions are immediate from the previous lemma:  a chain of divisorial (resp. principal) ideals in $B$ is contracted from a chain of divisorial (resp. principal) ideals in $A$, which stabilizes by assumption, hence the original chain stabilizes in $B$.

If $A$ is a valuation domain, $a, b \in B$, then WLOG $a \mid b$ in $A$ so that $ac = b$ for some $c \in A$.  But then $c = b/a \in L$, so $c \in A \cap L = B$ and $a \mid b$ in $B$.

Now if $A$ is integrally closed then we can write $A = \bigcap_\alpha V_\alpha$ for some collection of valuation overrings of $A$.  Then $B = A \cap L = \bigcap_\alpha (V_\alpha \cap L)$ is an intersection of valuation overrings of $B$, using the previous observation.

If $q \in L$ is almost integral over $B$, then we have $qI \subseteq I$ for some ideal $I$ of $B$.  Then also $qIA \subseteq IA$, i.e. $q$ is almost integral over $A$ as an element of $K$, and by assumption $q \in A$.  So $q \in A \cap L = B$.  (Alternatively you could use this approach to argue descent of integrally closed, because being integral is equivalent to $qI \subseteq I$ for an f.g. ideal ideal).

It is well-known that a domain is Krull iff it completely integrally closed and Mori.  For a reference, see section 2.4 of [these course notes](http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/gabelli/dispense/IdealNotes2.pdf) by S. Gabelli.

Being a Discrete Valuation Ring, i.e. a Noetherian valuation ring, is equivalent to being a Mori valuation ring.  See 2.15 in the linked notes.
$\square$

This list is by no means meant to be exhaustive.  But these observations are already enough to understand how the property of being Dedekind descends.

Because Dedekind domains are exactly the $1$-dimensional Krull domains, we have the following

> **Proposition**: Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain.  Then $B = A \cap L$ is Dedekind iff it is $1$-dimensional.

In particular this works with your assumption that $A$ is integral over $A \cap L$.

When $A$ is integrally closed and $A \cap L \subseteq A$ is integral, local properties of $A$ also readily descend.  In this case we can apply the following:

> **Lemma** [12.7 in R. Gilmer's *Multiplicative Ideal Theory*]: Let $B$ an integrally closed domain with field of fractions $L$, and $A \subseteq B$ an integral extension of domains.  For each prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $A$ contracting to $\mathfrak{p}$ in $B$, it holds $B_\mathfrak{p} = A_\mathfrak{q} \cap L$.

In particular if $A$ is integrally closed then we have observed that $A \cap L$ is integrally closed.  So if $A \cap L \subseteq A$ is integral, we can apply the lemma along with our previous descent observations and get results like:

> **Lemma** [Examples of local properties that descend when $A \cap L \subseteq A$ is integral]: Let $A \cap L \subseteq A$ be integral. If $A$ is Prüfer (i.e. locally a valuation domain) then $A \cap L$ is Prüfer.  If $A$ is locally a DVR then $A \cap L$ is locally a DVR.